# Estimate for weak solution in elliptic equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, elliptic-equations

- Let $B_1$ the unit ball closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$
- $u: B_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function in $H^1(B_1)$

If I have the following inequality:

(*) $\|u\|_{L^{\gamma_i}(B_{\frac{1}{2}})} \leq C\|u\|_{L^2(B_1)}$
where $\gamma_i = 2(\frac{n}{n-2})^i$ for $n>2$ and for all $i=1,2,3,\dots$ and $C$ is a positive constant.

How do I show that

$$\sup_{B_{\frac{1}{2}}} \leq C\|u\|_{L^2(B_1)} \text{ ?}$$

If I take $i \to \infty$ , I know $\gamma_i \to \infty$, and as the domain is $B_{\frac{1}{2}}$ which has finite Lebesgue measure, then $\|u\|_{L^{\gamma_i}(B_{\frac{1}{2}})} \to \|u\|_{L^\infty(B_{\frac{1}{2}})}$. Hence, I do not know how to get out of the impasse that has just appeared, because the only thing I know is that the $L^\infty$ norm of $u$ in that ball, dominates or is equal to $|u|$  ae.  How then does this supremum appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $\|u\|_{L^{\gamma_i}(B_{1/2})} \leq C\|u\|_{L^2(B_1)}$ for all $i$, and if $\|u\|_{L^{\gamma_i}(B_{1/2})} \to \|u\|_{L^\infty(B_{1/2})}$ as $i\to\infty$, then it would seem that $\|u\|_{L^\infty(B_{1/2})}\le C\|u\|_{L^2(B_1)}$.  You say that $|u|$ is dominated a.e. on $B_{1/2}$ by $\|u\|_{L^\infty(B_{1/2})}$ (which I agree with).  Doesn't it then follow that $\mathrm{ess}\sup_{B_{1/2}} |u|\le C\|u\|_{L^2(B_1)}$?

Is the issue that is worrying you the difference between supremum and essential supremum?  It seems obvious that we can't bound the supremum of $u$ if we only know things about $u$ which don't change if $u$ changes on a set of measure zero.

One caveat:  for my argument to make sense, in $\|u\|_{L^{\gamma_i}(B_{1/2})} \leq C\|u\|_{L^2(B_1)}$ we must have one $C$ for all the $i$.

Comment: The essetial supremum measures the largest value of a function less than sets of measure zero, roughly, the essential supremum does not "see" sets of measure zero.

Comment: I agree with your comment.